# Formulas or approximations for $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\|X\|} \right)$ or $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\|X\|^2} \right) $, $X\sim N(\mu, Id)$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

I want to compute or approximate the following expected values with some analytic expression:

$\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\|X\|} \right)$
and
$\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\|X\|^2} \right) $, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a multivariate isotropic, non-centered gaussian $X\sim N(\mu, Id)$.

For a general $X\sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ Gaussian, the variable $\frac{X}{\|X\|}$ is called the general projected normal distribution. This is a complicated distribution, whose moments don't seem to have closed form formulas.

However, for the simpler case where the covariance is the identity matrix, I wondered whether there's a way to obtain or approximate these expected values. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392703/expectation-of-a-non-central-chi-squared-distribution/2399452#2399452) comes close to what I need, asking for the expectation $\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{1+\|X\|^2} \right)$ and someone posted an approximation. [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588639/what-is-the-expected-value-of-x-i-x-2-when-x-sim-mathcaln-mu-sigma) other question asks for the second expectation, but asks specifically for the expectation formula, while I'm asking if there's some reasonable approximation.

Edit: Cross posted in CV [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/629670/formulas-or-approximations-for-mathbbe-left-fracx-x-right-x-si)

Comment: $\frac{\mathbf X}{\|\mathbf X\|}$ is a point uniformly distributed on a unit-radius (hyper)sphere centred at $\|\boldsymbol \mu\|$, so intuitively $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{\mathbf X}{\|\mathbf X\|} \right)$ is likely to be some fraction of $\boldsymbol \mu$ with that fraction being a function of $n$ and $\|\boldsymbol \mu\|$

Comment: The approximation I was planning to use is $\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{X}{||X||} \right) \approx \mu \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{ ||X||}\right)$, which maybe wouldn't be absolutely non-sensical according to your reasoning? I was thinking that different elements of $\mu$ may be scaled differently in $\mathbb{E} \left( \frac{X}{||X||} \right) $, but your reasoning suggests that maybe they aren't?

Comment: If you are using $\Sigma$ as a identity matrix then I would have thought you could rotate the whole thing without significant impact.  Empirically, for large $\|\boldsymbol \mu\|$ I seem to be getting about$ \left(1-\frac{n-1}{2 \|\boldsymbol \mu\|^2}\right)\frac{\boldsymbol \mu}{\|\boldsymbol \mu\|}$ but this is too small for small $\|\boldsymbol \mu\|$

Comment: The start of my first comment was wrong.  $\frac{\mathbf X}{\|\mathbf X\|}$  is a point distributed on a unit-radius (hyper)sphere centred at $0$ so its expectation is in the direction of $\boldsymbol \mu$ inside the ball

Comment: Of interest might be that square of the radial coordinate, used in the answers, follows a [non-central beta distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_beta_distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we let the $x\in \mathbb R^n$ be distributed as $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2 I)$, then it is clear that by symmetry the expectation value  $\mathbb E\left( \frac{X}{|X|^k}\right)$ is parallel to $\mu$. The value can be computed exactly as
$$
\mathbb E\left( \frac{X}{|X|^k}\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1-\frac{k}{2}\right)}{(2\sigma^2)^{k/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{}_1F_1\left(\frac{k}{2};\frac{n+2}{2};-\frac{|\mu|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,\mu,\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where ${}_1F_1(a;b;z)$ is Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function.

For certain values of $n$ and $k$ this can written in terms of more elementary functions e.g for $n=2$ $k=2$
$$
\mathbb E_{\mathbb R^2}\left( \frac{X}{|X|^2}\right) = \frac{1-e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{|\mu|^2}\, \mu.
$$

The $n$-dimensional integral for $(\ast)$ can be solved by utilizing the symmetry around $\mu$. Choose $r$ to be a radial coordinate and $\theta$ the angle to $\mu$, then the projection of the expectation value onto $\mu$ can be computed as
$$
\mathbb E\left( \frac{\mu\cdot X}{|\mu||X|^k}\right) =(2\pi\sigma^2)^{-n/2}e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}}\int_0^\infty dr\int_0^\pi d\theta \,r\,A_{n-2}(r\sin\theta)e^{-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{\mu r}{\sigma^2}\cos\theta}\frac{\cos\theta}{r^k},
$$
where $A_{n-1}(r)=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}r^{n-1}$ is the area of a $(n-1)$-sphere of radius $r$.

Comment: Thanks! Is there some reference that you could provide for this?

Comment: I just did the integral myself, so I do not have a reference, but I can try to add a few details on the calculation.

Comment: That would be awesome if possible. And maybe I can use it as inspiration to solve related problems afterwards. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, so I wouldn't know how to get from the integral to the final formula, but I checked the formula with simulations and it works like a charm. Thanks again!

Comment: in the first line, I think it should be $\sigma^2$ instead of $\sigma$ multiplying the identity. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, you are right.

Comment: In case you're interested, @Ben, I posted a follow-up question that maybe you're capable of answering https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4798674/covariance-of-fracx-x-with-x-sim-n-mu-sigma2-id-and-1f-1a

Comment: Hey @Ben, I'm trying to better understand this answer of yours. I have been looking for identities of the confluent hypergeometric function to identify how it emerges from the integral but without success. Would you mind providing some pointer to where I could find the connection between that integral and 1F1?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2 I)$. Let $k \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.

Using the identity ($q > 0, m > 0$)
$$
\frac{1}{q^m} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(m)}\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-qt}t^{m - 1}\,\mathrm{d} t,
$$
we have
\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|^k}\right) 
 &= \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{(\|X\|^2)^{k/2}}\right) \\[6pt]
 &= \mathbb{E}\left(X \cdot \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-t\|X\|^2}t^{k/2 - 1}\,\mathrm{d} t \right) \\[6pt]
 &= \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\int_0^\infty \mathbb{E}\left(X\mathrm{e}^{-t\|X\|^2}\right)t^{k/2 - 1}\,\mathrm{d} t \\
 &= \mu \cdot \frac{1}{\Gamma(k/2)}\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(2\sigma^2 t + 1)^{n/2 + 1}}\,\mathrm{exp}\left({-\frac{\|\mu\|^2 t}{2\sigma^2 t + 1}}\right) \cdot t^{k/2 - 1}\,\mathrm{d} t
\end{align*}
where we use
$$\mathbb{E}\left(X\mathrm{e}^{-t\|X\|^2}\right) = \mu \cdot \frac{1}{(2\sigma^2 t + 1)^{n/2 + 1}}\,\mathrm{exp}\left({-\frac{\|\mu\|^2 t}{2\sigma^2 t + 1}}\right).$$

For example, when $k=2, n=2$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{X}{\|X\|^2}\right) 
= \mu \cdot \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{(2\sigma^2 t + 1)^{2}}\,\mathrm{exp}\left({-\frac{\|\mu\|^2 t}{2\sigma^2 t + 1}}\right) \,\mathrm{d} t
= \mu \cdot \frac{1 - \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{\|\mu\|^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\|\mu\|^2}$$
which is the same as @Ben's result.