# Covariance of $\frac{X}{\|X\|}$ with $X\sim N(\mu, Id)$, and ${}_1F_1(a;b;z)$ properties

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, special-functions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I am interested in analytically computing the covariance of the variable $\frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert}$, where $X \in \mathbb{R}^d \sim N(\mu, I_d)$.

I have already found an analytic expression for the second moment matrix $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{XX^T}{\lVert X \rVert^2} \right)$ ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/605559/expected-value-of-the-outer-product-of-normalized-non-centered-gaussian-vector)), and for the first moment $\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert} \right)$ ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784989/formulas-or-approximations-for-mathbbe-left-fracx-x-right-or-m)):

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{XX^T}{\lVert X \rVert^2} \right) =
\frac{1}{d}{} A I_d + \frac{1}{d+2} B \mu\mu^T
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert}\right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} C \mu
\end{equation}

Where we have $$A = {}_{1}F_1\left(1; \frac{d}{2}+1; \frac{-||\mu||^2}{2}\right)$$

$$B = {}_{1}F_1\left(1; \frac{d}{2}+2; \frac{-||\mu||^2}{2}\right)$$

$$ C = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}+1-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}+1\right)}{}_1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{d+2}{2};\frac{-||\mu||^2}{2}\right)$$

Thus, we have that

$$Cov \left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert} \right) = \mathbb{E}\left( \frac{XX^T}{\lVert X \rVert^2} \right) - \mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert} \right) \mathbb{E}\left( \frac{X}{\lVert X \rVert} \right)^T = \frac{1}{d}{} A I_n + \left( \frac{1}{d+2} B - \frac{1}{2} C^2 \right) \mu\mu^T $$

Although the formula above works well, I am wondering whether there can be some simplification in either the terms $\left( \frac{1}{d+2} B - \frac{1}{2} C^2 \right)$ or just $C^2$, which involve Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function ${}_1F_1(a;b;z)$ and the gamma function.

Thus, is there any way to simplify the following formula using some ${}_1F_1(a;b;z)$ properties?

$$
\left( \frac{1}{d+2} \cdot {}_{1}F_1\left(1; \frac{d}{2}+2; \frac{-||\mu||^2}{2}\right) - \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}+1-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{d}{2}+1\right)}\right)^2 \cdot \left({}_1F_1\left(\frac{1}{2};\frac{d+2}{2};\frac{-||\mu||^2}{2}\right)\right)^2 \right)
$$

I'm particularly interested in knowing whether that term is different than 0 and its sign at different values of $||\mu||$ and $d$, but this seems difficult to do with that expression.